# Webview2 WPF Windows 10 - Custom Source URL with parameters, possible?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uri, webview2

I spent the night trying to solve this problem but couldn't unfortunately. Please show mercy, since I am not proficient in C#.

My MainWindow.xaml is pretty much from the MS support pages:

```
    <Window x:Class="TrayApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:wv2="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf;assembly=Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf"
        xmlns:r="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:local="using:clr-namespace:TrayApp"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="825" Width="500" 
        Deactivated="Window_Deactivated"
        ShowInTaskbar="False" 
        WindowStyle="None">
    
        <DockPanel>
            <wv2:WebView2 Name="webView"
                  Source = "https://website.com" />
        </DockPanel>
    </Window>
```

My goal is, whenever the webview2 control is launched the URL has to be dynamically changed to https://website.com/?param=hostname

I know that its possible to get hostname of a PC via `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("COMPUTERNAME")` however, I tried very many variations data bindings and other tricks, but nothing seems to work. Hopefully someone someone can help.

**UPDATE:**
Thanks to Klaus Gütters suggestion, it made click in my head and it works as intended now!

My MainWindow.xaml.cs looks like this:

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Hide_Window();
            string host = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("COMPUTERNAME");
            webView.Source = new Uri("https://website.com/?param=" + host);
```

And my MainWindow.xaml like this:

```
<wv2:WebView2 x:Name="webView"
                  Source = ""
```

Comment: Did you mean C**O**MPUTERNAME?

Comment: @LajosArpad ahahah yes of course.

Comment: Is this solving the issue?

Comment: @LajosArpad No, since the method isn't the problem. The problem is to generate a custom URL string and feed it to Source

Comment: Did you try to set Source from code-behind like `webView.Source = new Uri("https://website.com/?param=MyComputerName);`. If this works, go on and construct the Uri dynamically.

Comment: @KlausGütter  Thank you SO SO SO SO MUCH....Danke! Werde gleich updaten